# Querying MySQL to get price from 4 tables

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I am trying to get the **price of certain service** in a MySQL database, computed as follows:

I have 4 tables:

- **Services** (idService (*INT*), ...)
- **Dates** (idDate (*INT*), idService (*INT*), date (*DATETIME*), kilometers (*INT*), mounting(*BOOL*), ...)
- **Features** (idFeature (*INT*), description (*VARCHAR*), price (*FLOAT*), ...)
- **Features_Services** (idFeature (*INT*), idService (*INT*), units (*INT*), discount (*FLOAT*), ...)

Relations:

- **One to many between Dates and Services**: Thus, a service can take place along several dates, each one with its asociated **kilometers** (to quantify travel expenses, 0.6 EUR each one of them on final service price) and **mounting** (if *not active* in each date, service price will be *decremented* by a constant value, 100 EUR in my case)...
- **Many to many between Features and Services through Features_Services**: Thus, many services can have many features associated. Each feature has its single price, but also the relation has parameters like units and discount...

Well, with the following query, I get the price of a service correctly, **but only regarding the kilometers and mounting of the first date**...

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN dates.mounting = 0 THEN 
            SUM(features.price * features_services.units * (1 - features_services.discount / 100)) + 0.6 * dates.kilometers - 100
        ELSE 
            SUM(features.price * features_services.units * (1 - features_services.discount / 100)) + 0.6 * dates.kilometers
    END AS servicePrice

FROM features_services
JOIN features ON features_services.idFeature = features.idFeature       
JOIN dates ON features_services.idService = dates.idService                                         
WHERE features_services.idService = XXXXXXX 
GROUP BY dates.idDate LIMIT 1
```

The problem is **that I need to loop through all of the associated dates extracting kilometers and mounting**, and applying the neccesary corrections to the price...
Maybe with a select inside a select, for the dates??

Any help is much appreciated.
Than you in advance.

Comment: It's unusual to use a FLOAT data type with money. See DECIMAL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it using select subqueries. Here is the solution:

```
SELECT 
    features_services.idService AS cid,
    SUM(features.price * features_services.units * (1 - features_services.discount / 100)) + 
    (SELECT 0.6 * SUM(dates.kilometers) FROM dates WHERE dates.idService = cid) +
    (SELECT SUM(CASE when dates.mounting = 1 THEN 0 else -100 END) FROM dates WHERE dates.idService = cid) AS importeTotal
FROM features_services
JOIN features ON features_services.idFeature = features.idFeature
WHERE features_services.idService = XXXXXXXX
```

Thank you.